# Power BI - Dynamic rank leads to cartesian when second table added to table visualization

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

Power BI Desktop Version: 2.97.861.0 64-bit (September 2021)

I am attempting to create a dynamic rank in a table visualization of a Power BI Report that recalculates based on the filter the user applies

This is my current DAX formula…

```
Rank = 
VAR v_rank =

RANKX(
    ALLSELECTED('cust_income'),
    CALCULATE(SUM('cust_income'[Income])),
    ,
    DESC,
    Dense
    )

RETURN  
v_rank
```

Screenshot below is filtered for Customer ID = 1

The rank works as expected - it is specific to the Customer ID = 1 records

HOWEVER - as soon as I add `Product Desc` to the table visualization, I see the strange cartesian result on the right…

[image: cartesian]

There are only two tables. The relationship is a very basic 1:N using `Product Code`...

[image: erd]

How to keep `Product Desc` in my table visualization but eliminate the nonsensical rows that have no `Income` value?

Thank you for your insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
Rank = 
VAR v_rank =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE(cust_income[Income]),
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('cust_income'),
        CALCULATE(SUM('cust_income'[Income])),
        ,
        DESC,
        Dense
    )
)

RETURN  
v_rank
```

Comment: Just brilliant! Not only does this answer my question but somehow also solves the performance issue I was facing with my workaround filtering out blank Income values at the visualization level. Many thanks :)

Comment: I made a slight adjustment - COUNTROWS(VALUES(cust_income[Income])) >= 1. This handles Income values that occur more than once.

Comment: Rank = 
VAR v_rank =
IF (
    COUNTROWS(VALUES(cust_income[Income])) >= 1,
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('cust_income'),
        CALCULATE(SUM('cust_income'[Income])),
        ,
        DESC,
        Dense
    )
)

RETURN  
v_rank